# Options for skirting board on slightly different levels

Tags: baseboard, skirting

My kitchen floor is higher than my dining room floor and there is no door between them.

Since removing a thick carpet from the dining room and rescuing the wood floor there is now about an inch gap between the floor and the skirting board coming in from the kitchen.

I'm not sure what to so with the skirting board. At the moment I'm thinking of just ending the kitchen length at the boundary and then starting a new run in the dining room at the lower height.

Is there a more correct way to do it?

Image of boundary between kitchen and dining room:

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't go around that corner to the left, you could just use a tall piece of shoe molding or quarter round, but you'd still have to cover the end somehow

Comment: Ah it will be going round to the left to continue round the room. It only ends there because the dining room doesn't have any skirting at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different options that I'd consider:

1. Ordering made-to-measure skirting for the dining room that's taller than the skirting you have the kitchen, but with the same top profile. This allows the tops of all skirting (and hence the grooves) to line up.
2. Stepping it down with a transition piece. You can either cut at 45 degrees and have the transition piece run vertically, or cut at 22.5 degrees and have the transition piece run at 45 degrees. In the following diagrams the black diagonal lines represent cuts, while the blue lines represent one of the grooves on your skirting. Note that the 45 degree transition in version A leaves a gap underneath it, which will require wood filler before painting. Or alternatively the transition can be moved to the right to avoid this, version B, but this leaves the skirting looking too low at the end of the kitchen.

[image: skirting transition]

Comment: That's really useful. Thanks for the illustrations they really helped. I think I'll try making a 90 degree transition piece. It's only a 15mm step down though so not sure how accurate I'll be able to get.